# How do I replicate "Import project" in Android studio in Terminal in OS X

Tags: android, macos, gradle

I have this file system that I'm pulling from a repo and when I import it into android studio, it does this magic. Then I can do gradle assembleDebug and generate an APK. How do I do the importing in Terminal?

Comment: "How do I do the importing in Terminal?" -- what are you importing it into?

Comment: Into a folder in StudioProjects

Comment: What is "StudioProjects"?

Comment: A place where Android Studio stores projects